# Tensorboard with keras estimators

Tags: keras, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

When using keras estimators its easy to load up the default tensorboard just by pointing tensorboard at the model directory

```
  model_dir = "model_dir/"

  keras_estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
     keras_model=model, model_dir=model_dir)

  ....

  $> tensorboard --logdir model_dir
```

And this will give you some tensorboard  defaults but how do you add to this, for example if you want to put a summary writer for images or to include some custom tensorboard functions to add them to the dashboard , what code do you write and where do you call it from ?

Comment: are you looking for maybe callbacks? Have you taken a look at https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard ? If you want to save images that are not (a representation of) the network's weights, you will have to write a custom callback (like this one for example: https://gist.github.com/zaccharieramzi/f7dd5f0e34691d0a987e1e50b694ac03).

Comment: yes along those lines but I'm not sure how to hook the callback in to the estimator, I know once you have the model set up and trained you can call model.evaluate( ... callbacks= .. )  but is that the only place you can put this ? Is there a way to add a call back in the train step ? There is a callback hook for model.fit but if you are using estimators  ( tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator  )  you don't call .fit

Comment: Oh ok, I am not familiar with this way of doing things. If you have a custom training function where you do your own batching and `train_on_batch`, then you probably have to call the callbacks yourself at the right times. Take a look at this function https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L23 where they create the callback list and call the different hooks. You can just do the same in your training loop (I did it once and it worked just fine).

Comment: @NiallJG I'm stuck with the same issue, did you come across any solution?

Comment: No I didn't find a solution, tensorflow v2 / newer versions of Keras can handle tfrecords directly without setting up an estimator so I haven't been using  model_to_estimator or estimators for about a year, unless you're stuck with tf v 1 I'd reassess whether you need estimators at all now